# dynamically clipboard Python very difficult

Tags: python

Assuming that in the buffer of the clipboard there is the string "abc". I  press [command+v] two time on a text edit. The first output will be "abc". I press[command+v] the second time and i want the output is "def". I tried whit command sleep, importing the time module, but I don't like this solution. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
import clipboard 
str1="abc"
str2="def"
clipboard.copy(str1)
#PROBLEM
if(<--"pbpaste" command (copy command in unix) is launched by the input user-->):
   clipboard.copy(str2)
```

Obviously i can't write

```
if(clipboard.paste())
```

cause in this way the command was executed by the code, and i want that the IF was activate only by the user input "command+V" (pbpaste). I don't want use clipboard manager software. I like write.Help me please.

I also tried this code importing os module but doesn't work cause the input is viewed as string not as a command:

```
if(input()==os.system("pbpaste"))
```

Comment: Where is the `clipboard` module from?  Does it work on all OSes?  I am not sure what you want to do, but uou seem to want to intermix user control-key actions and program actions.  For this, you should use a GUI framework such as tkinter, where control/command-V can be intercepted to both paste and replace clipboard contents.

Comment: I don't want use a GUI framework. My purpose is this: I have an encrypted file with contains the login's credentials of all website to whom i am registred( url user and password).  The software get the  URL of active tab, and compares the string with file. When there is a match, it loads before the user into the clipboard buffer ( so I can paste it into the user form of the website ) . There isn't problem until now. So I want when I past user the software load the password in the clipbord.

Comment: That is pretty clear.  Unless your browser is text only, it *is* a GUI application built with some GUI framework.  What you are asking to do is write a private extension or plugin that ties into that framework.  So you need to find out how to do that with a particular browser.  I believe that some may require you to use JavaScript